# How do i send multiple arguments in android using socket.IO?

Tags: java, android, socket.io, client

I want to emit a JSON object like this, want to receive Auth Token in response. Is there any way I can emit multiple arguments in android using socket.io (client)?

I can emit multiple arguments in js like this;

```
       socket.emit('with-binary', 1, '2', { 3: '4', 5: Buffer.from([6, 7, 8]) });
```

This is my android code;

```
private void authenticateSocket() {
    try {
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("accessToken", "asdfasdfasf");
        jo.put("strategy", "jwt");

        JSONArray authentication = new JSONArray();
        authentication.put("authentication");
        authentication.put(jo);

       mSocket.emit("create",authentication,new Ack(){

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                Log.d(TAG, "call123: "+data);
            }
        });

        Log.d(TAG, "authenticateSocket: "+authentication);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of mSocket?

Comment: I'm using Socket.IO by NZkawa, mSocket is an Object of Socket class. here's the link to the socket I'm using.https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java